# error: non-aggregate type vector<int> cannot be inititalised with an initialiser list

Tags: c++, macos

I am writing C++ code in vs code on my Macbook. While using the C++ standard template library, i am writing the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> array={1,3,4};
    for(int x:array)
    cout<<x<<" ";
    return 0;
}
```

This code, on compilation gives the error that:

```
non-aggregate type vector<int> cannot be initialised with an initialiser list.
```

But when I re-write the code as below, it works totally fine.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<int> array;
    int val;
    int n;
    cout<<"Give me n:";
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        cin>>val;
        array.push_back(val);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In addition, I tried doing this in JetBrains Clion IDE, and I see that both versions of my code are working fine. Why this problem is happening?

Comment: You probably use an outdated compiler.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but both my vscode and CLION ide use the same compiler and it works perfectly in CLION. so it is not the compiler's problem.

Comment: Then the difference is in compiler flags that your IDEs use. Did you set any flags in VSC config?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes i think so i did it at the installation time of vscode, and this code gives 2 warnings also in vs code

Comment: Can you show us the revelant parts of VSC config then?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat first warning: 'auto' type specifier is a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions] , second warning:range-based for loop is a C++11 extension

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215326/discussion-between-dhruv-bansal-and-holyblackcat).

Comment: That certainly looks like your compiler either does not support C++11 (or better) or has not been told to use C++11 (or better). You likely need to add a `-std=c++11`  to the build options. I don't use either tool, so I don't know where this instruction needs to be added. If you add the option and get an error saying that the option is not recognized, your compiler is too old and needs to be updated to use this syntax.

Comment: compiles and runs fine with `gcc 7.5.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when i write this same code as:

The other version is not really **the same** code.

Your problem is with `std::vector` initializer list, probably arising from wrong compilation flags passed to your compiler. If you're using mac, try to download and install `clang`, then compile and run it. If it dosen't work then re-post.

Answer (score 1):

It worked on my environment (VS Code on Mac) by adding `"-std=c++11"` into the `"args"` list in `"tasks.json"` under `".vscode"` folder.